# How to convert Array to XML with integer index to super node

Tags: php, xml

I have an array like below :

```
...
array('info' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => $key1, 
                        'value' => $value1
                      ), 
                    array(
                        'key' => $key2, 
                        'value' => $value2
                     )
                 )
     );
...
```

I have XML convert function as below :

```
...
public function createXML($array, $xml = false)
{

    if($xml === false){
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<info/>');
    }

    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            $this->createXML($value, $xml->addChild($key));
        } else {
            $xml->addChild($key, $value);
        }
    }

    return $xml->asXML();
}
...
```

And I'm getting below XML :

```
<Info>
    <0>
        <Key>$key1</Key>
        <Value>$value1</Value>
    </0>
    <1>
        <Key>$key2</Key>
        <Value>$value2</Value>
    </1>
</Info>
```

But I want to get XML in below format :

```
...
    <Info>
        <Key>$key1</Key>
        <Value>$value1</Value>
    </Info>
    <Info>
        <Key>$key2</Key>
        <Value>$value2</Value>
    </Info>
...
```

How can I update createXML function so that can get above mentioned format XML?

Comment: wanted is invalid xml

Comment: This is not invalid XML, actually I'm getting same XML from a third party API response and after some check want to send same XML in other API request.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in here...

```
if(is_array($value)){
    $this->createXML($value, $xml->addChild($key));
} else {
```

Your doing this when you know that `$value` is an array.  This means that you will add all of the data (in your case the 2 elements) under the one `<info>` tag.  As you don't have an element name for these two values, it will use the numeric values you are getting.

If instead you pass them one at a time, you can add them under their own element...

```
if(is_array($value)){
    foreach($value as $value2){
        $this->createXML($value2, $xml->addChild($key));
    }
} else {
```